# h.264 Audio Out of Sync in Premiere

Tags: video, premiere, audio

I shot some video at an event last night with an ATEM TV Studio and recorded it via USB to my computer.

The files themselves play fine with VLC or Windows Media, but when I import them into Premiere the audio is out of sync with the video.

These files were captured with Media Express on 1080i5994. Capture format says AVI 8bitYUV.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that wouldnt work because the frame rate was being interpreted incorrectly causing the video to be half the length of the audio. And trying to fix the interpretation of the video only slowed down the audio. It was weird. I had to reencode the files and then edit.

For future reference in Media Express make sure the capture format is set to progressive.

Answer (score 1):

If the audio differs by the video at a constant offset, you can just unlink them in Premiere and then move the audio in the correct segment.

If the audio differs at a variable offset, then process the audio with adobe audition or something similar and make it match the video.